# Null to Blank values JSON sending in embed

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a command that will spit out a random drink to make. The problem is, some drinks have more ingredients and measurements than others which causes some of the keys to come back as null or None. I'm using `fix_data` to turn the Nones into blanks but it causes a huge gap in my embed. Is there any easier way to either display the data in the embed or an easier way to clear the None values in the JSON?

```
def fix_data(data):
    if type(data) is list:
        for i, e in enumerate(data):
            if e is None:
                data[i] = ''
            else:
                fix_data(e)

 if message.content.lower().startswith("!drink"):
        url = 'https://thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php'
        res = requests.get(url)
        data = res.json()
        fix_data(data)
        drinkname = data['drinks'][0]['strDrink']
        drinkimage = data['drinks'][0]['strDrinkThumb']
        instructions = data['drinks'][0]['strInstructions']
        ingredient1 = data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient1']
        ingredient2 = data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient2']
        ingredient3 = data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient3']       
        ingredient4 = data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient4']
        ingredient5 = data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient5']
        ingredient6 = data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient6']
        ingredient7 = data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient7']
        ingredient8 = data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient8']
        ingredient9 = data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient9']
        ingredient10 = data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient10']
        ingredient11 = data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient11']
        ingredient12 = data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient12']
        ingredient13 = data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient13']
        ingredient14 = data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient14']
        ingredient15 = data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient15'] 
        measure1 =  data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure1'] 
        measure2 =  data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure2'] 
        measure3 =  data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure3'] 
        measure4 =  data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure4'] 
        measure5 =  data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure5'] 
        measure6 =  data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure6'] 
        measure7 =  data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure7'] 
        measure8 =  data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure8'] 
        measure9 =  data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure9'] 
        measure10 =  data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure10'] 
        measure11 =  data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure11'] 
        measure12 =  data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure12'] 
        measure13 =  data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure13'] 
        measure14 =  data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure14'] 
        measure15 =  data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure15'] 

        msg = '**Drink**: \n{}\n\n**Ingredients**: \n{} {}\n{} {}\n{} {}\n{} {}\n{} {}\n{} {}\n{} {}\n{} {}\n{} {}\n{} {}\n{} {}\n{} {}\n{} {}\n{} {}\n{} {}\n\n**Instructions**: \n{}'.format(drinkname,measure1, ingredient1, measure2, ingredient2, measure3, ingredient3, measure4, ingredient4, measure5, ingredient5, measure6, ingredient6, measure7, ingredient7, measure8, ingredient8, measure9, ingredient9, measure10, ingredient10, measure11, ingredient11, measure12, ingredient12, measure13,ingredient13, measure14, ingredient14 , measure15, ingredient15, instructions)


    embed = discord.Embed(title="** DRINK BOT **", description=msg, color=0x9554af)
    embed.set_author(name="DRINK BOT", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/RI2iiLd.png")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url='{}'.format(drinkimage))
    embed.set_footer(text="DRINK BOT", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/RI2iiLd.png")
    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for-loop and if-statement to check every ingredient if None.

```
import requests

url = 'https://thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php'
res = requests.get(url)
data = res.json()

drinks = data['drinks'][0]
ingredients_list = ""

for i in range(1, 16):
    if drinks[f"strIngredient{i}"]:
        measure = drinks[f"strMeasure{i}"]
        ingredient = drinks[f"strIngredient{i}"]
        ingredients_list+=f"{measure if measure else ''} {ingredient}\n"

drinkname = drinks['strDrink']
drinkimage = drinks['strDrinkThumb']
instructions = drinks['strInstructions']

msg = f"**Drink**:\n {drinkname}\n\n **Ingredients**:\n {ingredients_list}\n **Instructions**: \n{instructions}"

print(msg)
```

Comment: Wow, I need to read more into loops and such. I could simplify a lot of my code. This works flawlessly but sometimes when measurement will have None yet the ingredient will have a value and the measurement still shows "None" on the embed send.

Comment: I have changed the code to only display *ingredient* if the *measure* is None

Comment: thank you, I had separated the for loop into 2 different sections and it was working but once again your code is a lot more efficient. I have a lot to learn.

Comment: No problem, mate!